# simplifying the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{s-1}a^n/n! $

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{s-1}a^n/n!  $$

Is there a nice way to simplify this series assuming $0 < a <1$ ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're assuming $0<a<1$? It's a polynomial in $a$, so it's entire.

Comment: Yes, without the restriction on $a$.  It involves the complete and incomplete gamma functions.  Is this homework?

Comment: @AdamHughes I want to apply this to a queuing theory formula so ya that assumption is required

Comment: @EricTowers Not homework I just want too verify whether this could be done

Comment: Poisson processes seem to be lurking in the background. Is this what interests you? Then, maybe the asymptotics in some limit you should explain (otherwise, this is not a real question).

Answer (score 1):

As said by Eric Towers, the result is quite simple since it is just the truncated series of $e^a$. $$\sum_{n=0}^{s-1}\frac{a^n}{n!}=\frac{e^a \Gamma (s,a)}{\Gamma (s)}$$ which is a very well behaved function for any value of $a$ since the lhs is just a polynomial of degree $(s-1)$